# Problems when running the plantuml.war file on Tomcat 7 in Synology

Tags: java, tomcat7, synology, plantuml

I have a Synology NAS (DS718+) running version 'DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4'

I have installed the Java8 package and Tomcat 7 package.

Then I downloaded and copied the plantuml.war file to the `/var/packages/Tomcat7/target/src/webapps` folder.

I am able to see the plantuml home page.
[image]
When I click on the 'View as SVG' (http://MY-SYNOLOGY-IP/plantuml/svg/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000) is get the following error.

[image]

I get the same error when I try to access the 'png' image.

[image]

I don't get this error when I run Tomcat 7 and add plantuml.war on my mac.

Why am I getting this error when I run it on Synology? and How do I fix this?